# How to style input with radio addon for error messages - twitter bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to style input field with radio addon for error message (.help-block). it works fine without  [radio addons](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-checkboxes-radios) . But with addon, text jump to new line under input field.

it is look like this

[image]

HTML

```css
<div class="input-group has-error">
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <input type="radio" name="answer" value="a">
  </span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your answer here..." name="a" id="a">
  <span class="help-block">The a field is required</span>
</div>
```

So what should I do that provided by bootstrap 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was doing it incorrectly.

```
<div class="form-group has-error">
  <label for="a">Answer A</label>
    <div class="input-group ">
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        <input type="radio" name="answer" value="a">
      </span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your answer here..." name="a" id="a">
   </div>
   <span class="help-block">The a field is required.</span>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: it should be `This field is required.` ;)

Comment: You are right but It is coming from laravel and input name is "a". So The "a" field is required.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show messages in same line, instead of `help-block` (if it suffices), you can use `tool-tip`, here is a   [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/logintomyk/96NDJ/1/)

**HTML**

```
 <div class="input-group has-error"> 
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <input type="radio" name="answer" value="a" class=""  />
    </span>

    <input type="text" class="form-control " placeholder="Your answer here..." name="a" id="a" /> 
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-container="" >
           This field is required
        </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry, I don't want it suffixed I want just bellow whole element.

Comment: Sorry if I am not so clear. check my answer what i want. thanks